# Is there no way available for retrieving posts using a search query/keyword from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to use [GraphAPI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/) for retrieving various posts using a search query/keyword from Facebook.

This is what I tried:

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/search?q=solareclipse&type=post",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

but I got this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#11) This method is deprecated",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 11,
    "fbtrace_id": "AZD1YH0em2M"
  }
}
```

Has Facebook completely taken back the privilege of searching through it's public posts or is there some other way available?

Comment: Correct. There is no way to search public posts

Comment: @WizKid well, that's bad. What about crawling through the posts? Is it legal or allowed by Facebook?

Comment: Not allowed by Facebook Terms of Service

Comment: @WizKid Okay! Is there any way to get posts from my news feed or posts from my friends's profile?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: @WizKid thanks for replying. Do you have any idea about Instagram API? Could you please tell me how can I get posts from instagram in my android app using various hashtags?

Comment: @WizKid Please reply.

Comment: I don't know anything about it but you can read about it at https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Graph API v2.0 it is no longer possible to search through public posts.

There is a public feed API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed), however the access is limited to certain media companies only.

Comment: Then can I get posts from my news feed or from my friends's profile?

Comment: Yes you can read all posts from you own account or your friends account, if you or your friend has allowed your Facebook App to get access to your walls post. For further information please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, I want to read posts from my newsfeed and not my timeline. `/me/feed` returns my timeline's posts. How can I get posts from my newsfeed?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/home As of October 6th, 2015, this endpoint is no longer available. So this means it is no longer possible to get access to the news feed. You are only able to get access to your own timelines post.

Comment: It means I can't read even the posts on my newsfeed. Graph API has so many limitations!!

Comment: Afaik they limited the feed request because of the exceeding traffic. I think your question is answered now even if you did not get the answer you wanted to hear ;-)

Comment: Hey, do you know how to use Instagram API? I want to get posts from Instagram in my android app using various hashtags. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Please use another question and mark this Answer as solved.

Comment: I have marked the answer as solved and for retrieving instagram posts I'm using Instagram4j library but it is causing some errors on which I've asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45802830/6144372 and you can find more details about the continuous errors it is causing in this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152966/discussion-between-hammad-nasir-and-razvan